# How to implement the PUT method using django-tastypie?

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I had successfully implemented the GET method. But when I call the PUT method it gaves the 401 unauthorized error. Please see code below,

```
class ShipmentResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Shipment.objects.all()
        list_allowed_methods = ['get', 'put']
        Authorization = Authorization()
        serializer = Serializer(formats=['json'], content_types={'json': 'application/json', })
```

Did I go wrong anywhere. Please solve my problem. Thanks..

Comment: Sorry it is working using CURL.

Comment: But I need to check my PUT in "Advanced Rest Client Application". This is google chrome plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share your error and the PUT call that you made?

If you're using a PUT call to update a resource you need to specify its detail uri:

example - `http://host:port/api/v1/shipment/1` (Note the id "1" at the end)